# JavaScript Object Within Another Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, mapael

I am using a jQuery plugin called [Mapael](http://www.neveldo.fr/mapael/) and am attempting to do something rather simple.

The "plots" object at the bottom of the function is going to add plot points to a map. The plot points are also objects.

My goal is to dynamically generate these plot points based on an external JSON file.  I have made a few plot points for practice and am storing them in the country object.

Is there any way to use the "country" object as the value for the "plots" object?

```
var country = {
    "XM": {
        value: 100,
        latitude: 22.99131,
        longitude: 54.77059
    },
    "VE": {
        value: 200,
        latitude: 64.42689,
        longitude: 145.23237
    },
    "SE": {
        value: 300,
        latitude: 8.96106,
        longitude: -15.09699
    }, 
    "XF": {
        value: 300,
        latitude: 50.93900,
        longitude: 55.38883
    }
}

$('.world').mapael({
    // ... other mapael objects to initialize map

    plots: {
        // country object
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Omit the braces and just reference the variable:

```
$('.world').mapael({
    // ...
    plots: country
});
```